Does 1 Corinthians 11:26 emphasize only Communion, or does it equally point to a celebration of the Second Coming and resurrection?
According to the Gospel, yes Jesus died but he also arose and was taken up to heaven.
1 Corinthians 11:26 (NET) states:

For every time you eat this bread and drink the cup, you proclaim the Lord’s death until he comes.

In taking the LORD's supper, we acknowledge His death. However, only untill He comes again. The Bible teaches that Jesus, God the Father, and the Holy Spirit will return and make their home with the Christian when they receive Christ by faith. Also, Christ rose physically having power over death. We are told in Acts that he ascended to heaven to be with the Father. Why does Paul teach only to remember the Lords death 1 Corinthians 11:26?

I’m voting to close this question because "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", Christianity.SE.

The Title question is difficult to parse and understand. ¶ The body discusses things that are a matter of doctrinal understanding (Christianity), not a question about what that specific verse was intended to mean (Hermeneutics). It would be better asked on Christianity Stack Exchange. It would also be better if it directed the question at specific denominations, such as those that celebrate the Eucharist as a sacrament.

The expression 'Jesus the Father and the Holy Spirit' is more than ambiguous. It has three possible meanings unless punctuation is added.

Thanks for your responses to my question.  I don't usually go on these sites and have really just read my bibleeach day for over 30years. I was fascinated to find out what kind of response the question would raise. The response was pretty much what I had expected. I think I will remain to avoid electronic sites and apps and stick to reading my bible for illumination. Thanks again and God bless you for taking time out to respond.

@CharlesStirling Why do you not give us the fruit of your 30 year study and why not answer your own question (which is both permitted and welcomed). Why do we celebrate or remember the death of Christ ? Why, indeed ? Tell us what you believe.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics and you get a vote from me for a question that deserves a well considered Christian answer

When Paul wrote that bit in 1 Corinthians chapter 11, he quoted the words of Jesus to those gathered in that upper room, the night before he died. He had not yet died. The resurrection from the grave had not happened (it couldn't, not until after Christ had died!)
It wasn't until after the resurrection, and the followers seeing Jesus ascend bodily up into the sky, to return to the Father in heaven, that they fully understood the significance of Jesus speaking about returning, coming again. The two who then appeared, dressed in white, confirmed that "This same Jesus, which is taken up from you into heaven, shall so come in like manner as ye have seen him go into heaven." Acts 1:3-11 A.V.
Then they knew what Jesus meant the night before he died, and the full significance of keeping that memorial supper. And that is why the Church has solemnly kept that act of remembrance, for our Lord is still to return to Earth in the same way that the disciples saw him leave.
It is now impossible for those who partake of the bread and wine appropriately not to equally think on his still-future spectacular return. They all know that there will be no more memorial supper on Earth once he returns. Their partaking is a witness both to his death and resurrection, as it is to his anticipated return.
The second sentence following quoting the text in question is extraneous as it has nothing to do with the matter in the text. Without that sentence, the question is clear and can be answered quite simply. The simple answer is that Paul does not teach only to remember the Lord' death and resurrection in that text. By including "until he comes", the Second Coming is given its proper place, after Christ's death and resurrection.

Excellent QuestionMany denomination in Christianity do put emphasis only on the Death and Crucifixion of Jesus during the rite of Communion.
However when we read the whole counsel of God, the Church celebrates much more than that.  We read the whole verse:

Every time you eat this bread and drink this cup, you do show the Lord's death until He comes. (1 Corinthians 11:26)

Notice the last phrase: until He comes.  The Passover Feast of the Jews was not an event celebrated by itself. It initiated the Feast of the Firstfruits.
This was a celebration of the beginning of life-sustaining food harvest.
And the same Paul mentioned this in his latter part of this letter to the Corinthians.

If in this life only we have hope in Christ, we are of all men most miserable. But now is Christ risen from the dead, and become the firstfruits of them that sleep...For as in Adam all die, even so in Christ shall all be made alive. But every man in his own order: Christ the firstfruits; afterward, they that are Christ's at His coming. (1 Corinthians 15:19-23)

While Paul observed, what we now call Communion, he---and his congregation---were well aware of the whole festival season. The Death of Jesus was to be celebrated, to be sure...but until He comes. There was always a view towards the awesome hope of the future Coming with the amazing resurrection of believers! The Resurrection transformed the crucifixion sorrow into a living hope. (1 Peter 1:3 begotten us unto a living hope by the resurrection of Jesus)
Application In modern church life, the pastors do well to observe Communion---however often they do it---but they should also celebrate "the coming again" with its resurrection scenario, of which the Firstfruits (Jesus) has ensured will happen! Maranatha!

The problem with the question is this statement: "The bible then teaches that Jesus … will come … when they receive Christ by faith.", which seems to be saying that the "until he comes" has already happened many many times, every time someone is baptized and accepts God's holy spirit. That's a very specific doctrinal position.

+1 for an interesting question, one aspect of which I've puzzled over myself.
I Cor. 11:23-26 - KJV
(23) For I have received of the Lord that which also I delivered unto you, That the Lord Jesus the  night in which he was betrayed took bread: (24) And when he had given thanks, he brake , and said, Take, eat: this is my body, which is broken for you: this do in remembrance of me. (25) After the same manner also  the cup, when he had supped, saying, This cup is the new testament in my blood: this do ye, as oft as ye drink , in remembrance of me.
(26) For as often as ye eat this bread, and drink this cup, ye do shew the Lord's death till he come.
That last verse is the sticky wicket, for me. Can’t have it both ways. Either this practice should have stopped the moment Jesus arose from the dead (or, at the very latest, Pentecost) - or one has to accept that Jesus did not rise from the dead, and we are to continue the Lord’s Supper, in remembrance, until He does return.
I ponder Jesus having not risen from the dead because of other passages, one of which is,
1 - Matt. 12:39-40 - (39) But he replied to them, “An evil and adulterous generation craves a sign. Yet no sign will be given to it except the sign of the prophet Jonah, (40) because just as Jonah was in the stomach of the sea creature for three days and three nights, so the Son of Man will be in the heart of the earth for three days and three nights.
Now, what if:  One day is a thousand years? Jesus will be in the heart of the earth for 3,000 years. He will only be available to us for this period of time (as the Holy Spirit?) before being 'called back' to His true abode. Therefore,
Heb. 3:15 - "While it is said, To day [while it is still called To-day] if ye will hear his voice, harden not your hearts, as in the provocation."
As for OP saying Paul teaches "only to remember Jesus' death;" that's incorrect. Paul speaks of His resurrection in many places, 1 Cor. 15:3-4 being the benchmark verses. However, the stated verse, 1 Cor. 11:26, is certainly interesting.

"this practice should have stopped the moment Jesus arose from the dead" — Why? You seem to be equating "resurrection" with "returning"." ¶ "we are to continue the Lord’s Supper, in remembrance, until He does return." — Correct. His return is often called "The Second Coming". The last two verses of the Bible are a plea for that return, so obviously the original Christians did not think that his resurrection (which had already happened) was the same as his return (to happen in the future).

@tblue, I think you're mistaken in conceiving verse 26 as having been declared at the same time and context that verse 24-25 was said being prior to Jesus's death, but it wasn't. Here Paul isn't relaying what Christ said at the last supper but expressing the state of affairs for Christian's post resurrection who celebrate the Lord's supper and are waiting Jesus's return.

Paul is actually not advising his audience to partake in "communion" here, or to only "acknowledge Christ's death".  He is explaining what the one true "Lord's Supper" meant and admonishing those who believe they are participating in it (v.19 "they which are approved"), but do so with a complete disregard to the actual meaning.
1 Corinthians 11:20-22

When ye come together therefore into one place, this is not to eat the Lord's supper.
21 For in eating every one taketh before other his own supper: and one is hungry, and another is drunken.
22 What? have ye not houses to eat and to drink in? or despise ye the church of God, and shame them that have not? what shall I say to you? shall I praise you in this? I praise you not.

Paul absolutely stresses the gospel to believe in is the one which includes Christ's death for the forgiveness of sins, burial, and resurrection for our justification only 4 chapters later:
1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

